# Cycle through an array with other arrays inside in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zad <-- FOR EXAMPLE, I WANT TO OUTPUT THIS KEY ON ALL THE ARRAYS
            [1] => 77c75f590b812c526937b06bfc3c6006e17afe2a
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => zad0xsis <-- FOR EXAMPLE, I WANT TO OUTPUT THIS KEY ON ALL THE ARRAYS
            [1] => 266612a67a909ef4b8af86b89778921950e3c561
            [2] => 0
        )

    [2] => 
)
```

How can I cycle through it so I can `echo` the key `0` of all the arrays inside the array?

Comment: This is programming 101 in PHP. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You iterate over the array. Each element of the array is itself an array. You access the first element of that inner array. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($mayarray as $element){
    echo $element[0];
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, now it works. I was stuck because I could just output the arrays with `foreach($r as $key=>$value)`. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($firstArray as $secondArray) {
    echo $secondArray[0];
}
```

Like that?

NOTE: Always check index existence, the above doesn't so will fail on index 2.